# Black Diamond Question Mark in XML

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, rss

I'm getting black diamond question mark's, and need to convert them to apostrophe's instead:

[image]

Here is my code I'll use, but what would I put for the black diamond question mark in `replaceOccurencesOfString`?

`[temp_str replaceOccurencesOfString:@"" withString:@"'" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp_str length])];`

I'm doing an iPhone app in Objective-C.

Comment: It would appear to be an encoding problem. Make sure the XML you are getting is correct and it's being parsed with the correct encoding.

Comment: I think you need to make sure you're specifying UTF8 encoding from wherever it is you're getting that xml from